# Skeleton CSS - how to span the width of the screen?

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm looking at www.getskeleton.com. My header and footer are supposed to span 100%. Can I do this without "breaking" the framework? Or am I supposed to restrict my layout to 960px?

Comment: Yes, skeleton is not fluent/fluid.

Comment: So - Skeleton cannot be used in my situation???

Comment: Not if you want a fluid layout. You should use the 960px grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want fixed elements, but it is one way of making elements full width without changing the behaviour of it's parents.

Note: similarly to absolute positioning, the elements would be taken out of the flow, and the top of the bottom would need to be changed accordingly. Padding to accommodate the height of each element should do it.

```
header,
footer{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

header{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

footer{
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I realize this is an older post, but I wanted to add my solution in case others in the future need the info:

Yes, you can make a multi-width layout still using Skeleton.  I took the Skeleton framework and also adapted some CSS/html from the "Magazine." sample site to meet my needs.

------  HTML CODE - Put in between 'Body' tags -------------

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="top-nav">
        <nav class="top-subnav">
            BUTTON · BUTTON · BUTTON · BUTTON · BUTTON · BUTTON · BUTTON · BUTTON
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>    

<div class="container">

    <header>
       <div class="three columns">
            <!-- LOGO --><img src="#" alt="Description"> 
       </div>
       <div class="thirteen columns">
            <nav class="main-nav">
                <ul class="main-nav">                            
                    <li>BUTTON</li>
                    <li>BUTTON</li>
                    <li>BUTTON</li>
                    <li>BUTTON</li>
                    <li>BUTTON</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
       </div>
    </header>   


    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <!-- Feature Banner image -->
    </div>

    <!-- ===== MAIN BODY ====== -->    

    <!-- LEFT COLUMN ---------- -->        
    <div class="four columns">
        <!-- Left column content goes here -->    
        <ul>                            
            <li>BUTTON</li>
            <li>BUTTON</li>
            <li>BUTTON</li>
            <li>BUTTON</li>
            <li>BUTTON</li>
        </ul>
    </div>   


    <!-- CENTER COLUMN ---------- -->        
    <div class="eight columns">
        <!-- Center column content goes here -->
        <h3>Main Title</h3>
        <h5 class="eventTitle">Article Title</h5><br />
        <p class="eventDetail">October 8, 2012 · 5pm - 8pm</p>
        <p class="eventDescrip">Skeleton is a small collection of well-organized CSS files that can help you rapidly develop sites that look beautiful at any size, be it a 17" laptop screen or an iPhone.
        </p>                                                                
    </div>


    <!-- RIGHT COLUMN ---------- -->        
    <div class="four columns">
        <!-- Right column content goes here -->
        <form class="search clearfix">
            <input type="search" placeholder="eg: Website Design" value="">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        <form class="search clearfix">
            <input type="search" placeholder="you@email.com" value="">
            <button type="submit">Sign-up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- ===== FOOTER ====== --> 

<div class="footer">    

        <footer class="container">
            <div class="four columns">
                <header><h6>Sample Title</h6></header>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>


            <div class="four columns">
                <header><h6>Sample Title</h6></header>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

           <div class="four columns">
                <header><h6>Sample Title</h6></header>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                        <li>Link</li>
                    </ul>
            </div>


            <div class="four columns textRight">
                   <span class="contactTitle">Business Name</span> <br />
                   12345 Main Road<br />
                   City, CO 80334<br />
                   (505) 555-5555<br />
                   Contact Us
            </div>

        </footer>
</div>

<div id="Credits">
Website Design by Dominical Design & Development · www.dominicaldesign.com · Indian Hills, Colorado
</div>
```

==================================================

......   then ..........
add the following CSS code to your standard Skeleton "layout.css" file

------- CSS CODE ---------------------------------

```
* { 
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body    {
color: #333333;
padding: 0px;   
    }

img {
max-width: 100%;
}


#top    {
width: 100%;
background: #069;
border-bottom: 3px solid #FC6;
padding: 8px;
margin: 0px;
}

nav.main-nav    {
text-align: right;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 110px 0px 0px 0px;
color: #666666;
}

nav.top-subnav  {
font-size: 11px;
color: #f6f6f6;
text-align: center;
}

nav.main-nav ul li {
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 20px; 
}

#Feature-Banner {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.footer {
width: 100%;
background-color: #063;
color: #f6f6f6;
margin: 20px auto 0px auto; 
padding: 20px 0px;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 18px;
}

.footer ul li   {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
line-height: 16px;
font-size: 10px;
}

.footer h6 {
color: #CCC;
margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;    
}

.textRight  {
text-align: right;  
}

.contactTitle   {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 11px;
}

#Credits    {
width: 100%;
font-size: 11px;
background-color: #033;
color: #cccccc;
text-align: center; 
padding: 20px 10px;
letter-spacing: 0.09em;
border-top: 1px solid #444444;
}
```

==========================================

That should give you the following:

Full width color bar at top, with option to add link/navigation in it
Header area for logo, main navigation, banner/feature graphic
3-column centered layout for the body
Full-width footer and credits bar down below

Hope this helps someone out there!
Share the knowledge!  :)
≈

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I knew there was a way to do this without completely obliterating the original grid system.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Snippet of code from the Skeleton Example page, the HTML wraps the container inside of another div. In the example it was a full image background that went from one end of the screen to the next using

```
background-image: url('../images/values-bg.jpg'); 
background-size: cover;
```

in the css file under `.values`
I simplified it to a gray background but all you would do is include the values above with your link to your image and you would be good to go.
I hope this better answered your question.

```
<div class="section values">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one-third column value">
      <h2 class="value-multiplier">67%</h2>
      <h5 class="value-heading">Purchase Increase</h5>
      <p class="value-description">Percentage of users more likely to purchase on mobile friendly site.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third column value">
      <h2 class="value-multiplier">90%</h2>
      <h5 class="value-heading">Multi-device Users</h5>
      <p class="value-description">Most of the world accesses the internet on multiple devices.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-third column value">
      <h2 class="value-multiplier">66%</h2>
      <h5 class="value-heading">Sad Users</h5>
      <p class="value-description">Percentage of users that are frustrated with page load times.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.values {
background-color: #aaa;
color: #fff;
padding-bottom: 5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nope. even if you give width=100% it wont work. because web page is split into 2 parts vertically. your header is displayed in the right part. it would be better if you use Tiles.

Answer (score 0):

One option for pseudo-full screen is to nest your container divs inside your semantic html5 tags or larger divs.

Skip to http://lostworldsfairs.com for a great example. See explanation below.

Start with your html:

```
<body>
 <header id="masthead">
  <div class="container sixteen columns">
   <hgroup>
    <img class="scale-with-grid" src="images/logo.png" />
    <h1>Masthead Title</h1>
    <p>Website tag line</p>
   </hgroup>
  </div>
 </header>

 <section id="main">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="two-thirds columns">
    <header>
     <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </header>
    <p>Meat of the page</p>
   </div><!-- close column -->
   <div class="one-third column">
    <p>side column stuff</p>
   </div><!-- close column -->
  </div><!-- close container -->
 </section>

 <footer id="attribution">
  <div class="container">
   <p>attribution</p>
  </div><!-- close container -->
 </footer>
</body>
```

Then, your css:

```
header,section,footer{
 overflow:auto;
}

header#masthead{
 background:#ccc;
}

footer#attribution{
 background:#ccc;
}
```

Now, your larger elements fill the space while your container divs are positioned nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those who are still looking for the answer as I was 15 mn ago, here is what I did. I do not use the skeleton boilerplate on an element I want at 100% width. For example i want a full width for the nav at the top but i also want a main content and a sidebar. here is a bit of the code

```
<nav class="navig-bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="pages">Page 1</li>
        <li class="pages">Page 2</li>
        <li class="pages">Page 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <section class="eleven columns">Main Content</section>
    <aside class="five columns">Sidebar Content</aside>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.navig-bar{width: 100%;}
    .navig-bar ul{list-style: none;text-align: center; }
        .navig-bar ul li{display: inline-block;}
```

This will get the job done, at least it works very well for me.